# Functoriality of indiscernible sequences

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, order-theory, automorphism-groups

Let $T$ be a first order theory of, say, some type of combinatorial geometries which contain indiscernible sequences of points. Let $(\Gamma,\mathcal{O})$ be a model of $T$, where $\Gamma$ is the geometry and $\mathcal{O}$ an indiscernible sequence of points in $\Gamma$. I will suppose that $\mathcal{O}$ generates $\Gamma$ for the sake of convenience, and I will suppose that $\mathcal{O}$ is ordered by "$<$."

I will use the following form of indiscernibility: for any finite ordered tuples $(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)$ and $(\omega_1',\ldots,\omega_n')$ of (different) points in $\mathcal{O}$ for which $\omega_1 < \omega_1 < \ldots < \omega_n$ and $\omega_1' < \omega_1' < \ldots < \omega_n'$, there is an automorphism $\alpha$ of $\Gamma$ which preserves $\mathcal{O}$, and which maps $\omega_r$ to $\omega_r'$ for all $r \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

My question is the following: suppose $\gamma: \mathcal{O} \mapsto \mathcal{O}$ is a map which preserves $\leq$ -- that is, a *morphism* of indiscernible sequences in some sense. Does $\gamma$ induce a morphism of geometries ? (Which would have the form $\overline{\gamma}: \Gamma = \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle \mapsto \langle \gamma(\mathcal{O}) \rangle$, where $\langle X \rangle$ means the geometry generated by $X$.)

Some additional properties on $\gamma$ are allowed if necessary. For instance, one might suppose that $\mathcal{O}$ and $\gamma(\mathcal{O})$ have the same order type.

**Note**: that I ask that $\gamma$ preserves $\leq$ and not $<$, in order to have a sufficiently general notion of morphism.

Comment: I'm confused. Let's say $T$ is the theory of projective planes. If $\mathcal{O}$ is a sequence of points, then for example for $a,b\in \mathcal{O}$, there is a unique line through $a$ and $b$. Let's say $\gamma$ collapses $a$ and $b$. Where do you propose to send the line?

Comment: I guess a similar question is: what exactly do you mean by a morphism of geometries?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: a morphism $\gamma': G \mapsto G'$ between point-line geometries maps points to points and lines to lines, such that if point $x$ is incident with line $Y$ in $G$, then $\gamma'(x)$ is incident with $\gamma'(Y)$. If $\gamma'$ would collapse points $a$ and $b$, then $ab$ should be sent to some line incident with $a = b$.

Comment: Ok, so you have to choose *some* line incident with $a=b$. I don't see any reason why every weakly order preserving map $\gamma$ of $\mathcal{O}$ should extend to a map of geometries in general, and even if it does I'm not sure I would say the map is "induced" by $\gamma$, because there's no reason for it to be unique.

Comment: Of course, if you have a model-theoretic structure $M$ and an indiscernible sequence $I$ in $M$ such that the substructure generated by $I$ is $M$ itself, then any $<$-preserving map $I\to I$ induces an embedding $M\to M$. It's the preserving $\leq$ instead of $<$ that gets you into trouble. And yes, there can be non-trivial $<$-preserving maps $I\to I$ when $I$ is infinite (think of $I$ indexed by a dense linear order). The key word here is "Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski model".

Comment: @AlexKruckman : indeed, I was not thinking about "induced" in the strict sense, because many morphisms could arise in principle. My idea was to consider sequences of isomorphisms $(\gamma_n)_n$ of $\Gamma$ that preserve $\mathcal{O}$, and that "converge" to $\gamma$ on $\mathcal{O}$, hoping that the sequence would lead to a morphism of $\Gamma$. (The fact that $\mathcal{O}$ is indiscernible, makes me think that its points are "so independent," that one could create morphisms $\Gamma \mapsto \Gamma$ from $\leq$-preserving maps of $\mathcal{O}$.)

Comment: @AlexKruckman : the structure $M$ is "generated by $I$": how is "generated by" defined here ? Do you have a standard reference for this embedding property ?  Thanks !

Comment: "Generated" means as a substructure, i.e. close up under the function symbols in the language. The embedding property is easy to prove: a map from a generating set determines at most one map from the whole structure, and this is an embedding exactly because increasing tuples from $I$ have the same types. For a related reference, again: look up Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski models in any textbook in model theory.

Comment: @AlexKruckman : suppose that $I$ is some set of lines in a geometry with points and lines, and suppose $M$ is generated by $I$ in the following sense: $M$ is the only subgeometry (of the same type as $M$) of $M$, which contains the lines of $I$. How would your embedding property translate to this situation ? Example: suppose $M$ is a projective space. Then we can generate $M$ in a classical sense (= in your sense) by the lines in $I$ and any point on any line of $I$. How does the embedding property applies ?